# CSS кнопка с градиентом

Tags: css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как на CSS можно сделать вот такую кнопку с градиентом, и чтобы потом при наведении происходила инверсия градиента (цвета менялись местами)? Есть ли какие-то онлайн-сервисы для генерации таких кнопок с градиентом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ | http://www.cssportal.com/css-gradient-generator/ | http://angrytools.com/gradient/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(51, 106, 206, 1) 0%, rgba(57, 114, 213, 1) 50%, rgba(35, 90, 191, 1) 50%, rgba(1, 60, 163, 1) 100%);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(1, 60, 163, 1) 0%, rgba(35, 90, 191, 1) 50%, rgba(57, 114, 213, 1) 50%, rgba(51, 106, 206, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
button{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius:20px;
  color: #fff;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

button:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform:rotate(-5deg) translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
}
button:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform:rotate(-5deg) translateY(50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0ff 0%,#0ff 50%,#f00 51%,#f00 100%);
}
button:hover:before{
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0ff 0%,#0ff 50%,#f00 51%,#f00 100%);
}
button:hover:after{
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);
}
```

```html
<button type="button"><span>Задать вопрос по комплектации</span></button>
```

Там правильные градиенты которые надо себе выбери